# Extracting n-grams of 3 contiguous characters and words

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

The function below (which I found in [this](https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html) blog post of **Chris van den Berg**) extracts all n-grams of 3 contiguous characters in a string:

```
import re

def ngrams(string, n = 3):
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD', r'', string)
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

As an example, passing the string `Stack Overflow` to the function defined above will return the following list:

```
print(ngrams('Stack Overflow', n = 3))

['Sta', 'tac', 'ack', 'ck ', 'k O', ' Ov', 'Ove', 'ver', 'erf', 'rfl', 'flo', 'low']
```

My goal is to modify this function so that it includes both n-grams of 3 contiguous characters **and** words. That is, for the same example shown above, I would like the output to be the following:

```
['Stack', 'Overflow', 'Sta', 'tac', 'ack', 'ck ', 'k O', ' Ov', 'Ove', 'ver', 'erf', 'rfl', 'flo', 'low']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
import re

def ngrams(string, n = 3):
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD', r'', string)
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return string.split(' ') + [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

print(ngrams('Stack Overflow', n = 3))
```

Which gives you:

```py
['Stack', 'Overflow', 'Sta', 'tac', 'ack', 'ck ', 'k O', ' Ov', 'Ove', 'ver', 'erf', 'rfl', 'flo', 'low']
```